# Learning about a hidden distribution behind Bernoulli trials

Tags: estimation, bernoulli-distribution

Consider a process where a *'probability'* $p$ is drawn from a fixed but unknown distribution $D$ supported on $[0,1]$ and then $y$ is drawn from Bernoulli distribution with parameter $p$. If $y_1,y_2..y_n$ are drawn by this process independently, then a reasonable estimator for $E_D[p]$ is $\sum_{}y_i/n$. Is there a distribution-free approach to estimate $E_D[f(p)]$ for any generic function $f$ ?

---

As $E[y^m]=E[y]$ for $m>0$, I doubt that $y$'s can tell us anything about $D$ apart from its expectation. What if we also know that $p_1\le p_2 \le . . \le p_n$?

Comment: Is $f$ given or assumed unknown?

Comment: $f$ is given. In the specific problem I am working on, it's differentiable and concave.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\E}{\operatorname{E}}$This is nowhere close to a solution but it connects higher moments of $p$ to your data. Maybe it'll help if $f$ is a polynomial?

I'm assuming that $y_1,\dots,y_n\mid p \stackrel{\text{iid}}\sim \text{Bern}(p)$ with $n$ non-random. Let $S = \sum_{i=1}^n y_i$ so $S\mid p\sim\text{Bin}(n,p)$.

Let $G(z\mid p) = \E(z^S\mid p)$ be the conditional probability generating function of $S$. We have
$$
G(z\mid p) = \sum_{s=0}^n {n\choose s} (pz)^s(1-p)^{n-s} = (1-p + pz)^n
$$
by the binomial theorem in reverse.

It is a standard result that
$$
G^{(k)}(1\mid p) = \E\left[\frac{S!}{(S-k)!}\mid p\right]
$$
(i.e. derivatives of $G$ give factorial moments of $S$) and I can see that
$$
G^{(k)}(1\mid p) = \frac{n!}{(n-k)!}p^k
$$
for $k \leq n$. This means that the marginal PGF of $S$ is
$$
G(z) = \E(z^S) = \E_D(G(z\mid p)) = \E_D((1-p+pz)^n).
$$
Differentiating here, and assuming I can exchange differentiation and integration, I have
$$
G^{(k)}(1) = \frac{n!}{(n-k)!}\E_D(p^n)
$$
so e.g.
$$
\E(S) = G'(1) = n \E_D(p)
$$
and
$$
\E(S(S-1)) = G''(1) = n(n-1)\E_D(p^2).
$$

Unfortunately it seems we only have one observation of $S$ so this might not be actually helpful, but it at least connects $S$ to higher moments of $p$.

If $n$ is sufficiently large we could partition the sample into $m$ groups of $k$ (so $n = mk$) and then take $S_1,\dots,S_m \mid p \stackrel{\text{iid}}\sim \text{Bin}(k, p)$ which would allow for some law of large numbers type estimators.

Comment: Thanks for the response. If I have understood it correctly, I would need to draw all $y_i$'s which are summands of a particular $S_j$ with the same probability $p$. This inhibits the approach mentioned in the end. If there were no such restrictions on $p$, $E[S(S-1)]/(n(n-1))$ would be off from $E_D[p^2]$ by $var_D[p]$ which puts us in a chicken and egg situation.

Comment: But I think we could make partitioning work, if we assume that the hidden variables $p_i$'s are in increasing or decreasing order and the sample is large enough. For then we could partition data such that the $p_i$'s in each partition are more or less the same. This feels like inefficient use of the data given the constraint on $p_i$'s.

Comment: @bleh ah I see I didn’t appreciate that every $y_i$ has its own $p_i$. I’ll have to think about that and update if I come up with anything

Answer (score 1):

This is similar to a Bernoulli factory problem. However, your problem has a solution only if *f*(*p*), in the interval [0, 1]—

- Is continuous, and
- is either constant on the interval [0, 1] and polynomially bounded away from 0 and 1

(Keane and O'Brien 1994).

Functions that meet these conditions are called *factory functions*, and only factory functions admit unbiased estimators when given an unlimited supply of Bernoulli(*p*) random variables (Łatuszyński et al. 2009/2011).

Merely being differentiable and concave is not enough for *f* to have an unbiased estimator. (Although being concave may simplify matters in designing an appropriate algorithm, depending on the function *f* in question, to Jensen's inequality.)

REFERENCES:

- Keane, M. S., and O'Brien, G. L., "A Bernoulli factory", ACM Transactions on Modeling and Computer Simulation 4(2), 1994.
- Łatuszyński, K., Kosmidis, I., Papaspiliopoulos, O., Roberts, G.O., "[Simulating events of unknown probabilities via reverse time martingales](http://arxiv.org/abs/0907.4018v2)", arXiv:0907.4018v2 [stat.CO], 2009/2011.

Answer (score 0):

Take $f = -x^2 + x$. It is concave and differentiable, as specified. For any $\alpha \in [0,1]$, define $D_{\alpha} := \alpha\delta(p-\frac14) + (1-\alpha) \delta(p-\frac34)$, where $\delta$ is the Dirac delta. If we choose $p \sim D_{\alpha}$ we *always* get $f(p) = \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{16} = \frac{3}{16}$, for *any* $\alpha \in [0,1]$. Thus $E_{D_{\alpha}}[f(p)] = \frac{3}{16}, \forall \alpha \in [0,1]$.

Let's assume we can observe $n$ of your trials. We seek an estimator $E: \{0,1\}^n \to \mathbb{R}$. Whatever $E$ is, it will have to give similar answers for sequences distributed $B(n, \frac14)$ and $B(n, \frac34)$ (corresponding to $\alpha=1$ and $\alpha=0$, respectively).

It seems to me that for that to hold, you will have to tailor your estimator to this given problem instance. I think you cannot find a general estimator (not without making further assumptions).

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am not sure I follow your arguments. Why can't there be an estimator which gives similar answers for $B(n,1/4)$ and $B(n,3/4)$? The sample variance is an example of such an estimator.
On the other hand for the original problem, the sample likelihood is simply $(E_D[p])^{\sum{y_i}}(1-E_D[p])^{n-\sum{y_i}}$ and depends only on the expectation of the hidden distribution, which is why I think it is impossible to infer anything else about $D$. But under the monotonicity constraint on $p_i$'s I believe we can do something.

Comment: @bleh Sorry I wasn't clear. I think the variance is the tailoring I was referring to - if you take $\alpha = 0.5$ then the variance is no longer informative. At the end of the day, you observe a sequence arising from iid $Bernoulli(\lambda), \lambda := \int D(p) dp$. I feel (and I might be mistaken) you cannot expect to learn anything about $f(p)$ without some knowledge of $D$. All this is true ignoring your assumption of mootonicity for $p_i$ (I did not give much thought to that case).